# shell script for password protected zip file creation

Tags: file, shell, zip, creation

Its an web application,  statement generation & reporting system dealing in huge numbers upto terabytes data. in this application we are using shell scripting for creating password protected zip file. When we tested this application on our development Server it is working fine. This script or zip file creation command are working properly for some server but not working on another server with similar hardware and OS. If we use  file with huge sizes or folders (having more than 400 files) in that case this command failed. any pointers plz?

Comment: If you want any help at all, at least paste the commands you are running, the differences between the two servers (OS, versions, etc), and anything else that may help.

Comment: What error message do you get? What command did you use to create the zip file? Which OS? What's different on the servers that it fails on?

Answer (score 0):

Some file systems have limits on the size of files (usually 2Gb or 4Gb) and even the number of files in a directory.  It might be worth looking at what the underlying file systems are on the working and non-working servers, to see if there's a pattern.

Comment: Error msg is - bash: /data4/OPERATIONS/bin/zip: The parameter or environment lists are too long. there is no difference between the two servers except one is in DMZ and another is in secure zone.

Comment: plz find below the shell script for this operation. What this script does is to collect many previously built PDF files and put that in a folder and zip it.

Comment: ###############Start of Move PDF To ENTERPRISE_CODE Folder & CREATE ZIP FILE#########################
 if test $jobsel = "3"
    then
    echo Start time for Move PDF To ENTERPRISE_CODE Folder and CREATE ZIP FILE for this $BD bill date : `date`  >> $timelog
    C=`grep "#" $DATA/Billoncd.txt | wc -l`
    cd $POSTSCRIPT/$BD
    S=`find ./ -name '*.pdf' | wc -l`
    echo " IN FILE : $C OUT FILE : $S "

Comment: if [ $S -eq $C ]
        then
        DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
        cd $POSTSCRIPT/$BD
        cat $DATA/Billoncd.txt | awk -F# '{print $1"_"$7"_"$4}' | sort -u | awk '{ print "mkdir -p "$1}' > make_directory.txt

        . make_directory.txt

        cat $DATA/Billoncd.txt | awk -F# '{print "mv "$2"-"$4".pdf $POSTSCRIPT/$BD/"$1"_"$7"_"$4}' > mv_pdf.txt

Comment: . mv_pdf.txt

        cat $DATA/Billoncd.txt | awk -F# '{ print "zip -P "$8" "$1"_"$7"_"$4".zip " $1"_"$7"_"$4"/*"}' | sort -u > make_zip.txt

        
        . make_zip.txt

        
        cd $POSTSCRIPT/$BD
        cat $DATA/Billoncd.txt | awk -F# '{ print "Password is "$8" for "$1"_"$7"_"$4".zip" }' | sort -u > $POSTSCRIPT/password_$BD.txt

Comment: cat $DATA/Billoncd.txt | awk -F# '{print $1"_"$7"_"$4}' | sort -u | awk '{ print "rm -r "$1}' > rm_directory.txt

        . rm_directory.txt

        alias rm=rm
        rm make_directory.txt mv_pdf.txt make_zip.txt rm_directory.txt

    else
       echo "\n\n\t\t\t\tPDF file count: $S and $DATA/Billoncd.txt file count :$C both count doesn't match Please check it."
    fi
    echo End time for Move PDF To ENTERPRISE_CODE Folder and CREATE ZIP FILE for this $BD bill date : `date`  >> $timelog
  

 fi